# Timeout on LoadBalancer exposing ECS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs

I'm currently trying to expose 2 services from my ECS cluster on a loadbalancer with a HTTP listener redirecting to a HTTPS listener (which is forwarding to the target groups of my services, depending on the host-header).

I registered the certificates with AWS Certificate Manager, but unfortunately I get timeouts when I'm trying to hit the URLS on my browser.

I am deploying those resources with Terraform :

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nginx-tg" {
  name                        = "nginx-tg"
  target_type                 = "ip"
  protocol                    = "HTTP"
  port                        = "80"
  vpc_id                      = var.vpc-id
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "apache2-tg" {
  name                        = "apache2-tg"
  target_type                 = "ip"
  protocol                    = "HTTP"
  port                        = "80"
  vpc_id                      = var.vpc-id
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "nginx-certificate" {
  certificate_arn = var.nginx-certificate-arn # subdomain1.domain.com
  listener_arn    = aws_lb_listener.test-cluster-lb-https-listener.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "apache2-certificate" {
  certificate_arn = var.apache2-certificate-arn # subdomain2.domain.com
  listener_arn    = aws_lb_listener.test-cluster-lb-https-listener.arn
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "test-cluster-lb-https-listener" {
  load_balancer_arn           = aws_lb.test-cluster-elb.arn
  port                        = "443"
  protocol                    = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy                  = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn             = var.listener-certificate-arn

  default_action {
    type                      = "redirect"
    redirect {
      port                    = "443"
      protocol                = "HTTPS"
      status_code             = "HTTP_301"
      host                    = "home.domain.com"
      path                    = "/"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "nginx-listener-rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.test-cluster-lb-https-listener.arn
  action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx-tg.arn
  }
  condition {
    host_header {
      values = [var.nginx-url]
    }
  }
  priority = 1
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "apache2-listener-rule" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.test-cluster-lb-https-listener.arn
  action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.apache2-tg.arn
  }
  condition {
    host_header {
      values = [var.apache2-url]
    }
  }
  priority = 2
}
```

And here is the ECS services declaration :

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "nginx" {
  name                        = "nginx"
  launch_type                 = "FARGATE"
  cluster                     = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition             = aws_ecs_task_definition.nginx_task.arn
  desired_count               = 2

  network_configuration {
    subnets                   = [var.private-sn-az-1, var.private-sn-az-2]
    security_groups           = [aws_security_group.service-sg.id]
    assign_public_ip          = true
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn          = aws_lb_target_group.nginx-tg.arn
    container_name            = "nginx"
    container_port            = 80
  }

}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "apache2" {
  name                        = "apache2"
  launch_type                 = "FARGATE"
  cluster                     = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.id
  task_definition             = aws_ecs_task_definition.apache2_task.arn
  desired_count               = 2

  network_configuration {
    subnets                   = [var.private-sn-az-1, var.private-sn-az-2]
    security_groups           = [aws_security_group.service-sg.id]
    assign_public_ip          = true
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn          = aws_lb_target_group.apache2-tg.arn
    container_name            = "apache2"
    container_port            = 80
  }

}
```

The security group of the services allows all the requests from my loadbalancer on port 80 !

It's my first post so I may have been unclear on some points, if you need the rest of the resources declaration feel free to ask me :)

Thank you in advance !!

**What I tried** : Target group was exposing port 8080, switched it to 80.

**What I expected** : Thought that my service was only listening on port 80, so changing it would make the timeout go.

**What actually happened** : Still got a timeout when i'm trying to accesss the urls (subdomain1.domain.com & subdomain2.domain.com)...

Comment: You seem to be guessing at the port your nginx and apache tasks are listening on. You need to verify those docker containers are actually configured to listen on port `80`. Include the ECS Task Definition in your question if you need help with that. Also, can you show the actual security group rules that are attached to the load balancer, and the rules attached to the ECS services?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the lack of informations! It was indeed a problem in my LoadBalancer security group (it was only listening on port **80**). I feel a bit ashamed that I got tricked by this.... Thank you very much for your help ! :)